# Innocent range based for loop not working

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, initializer-list

The following does **not** compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a{},b{},c{},d{};

    for (auto& s : {a, b, c, d}) {
        s = 1;
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_5Izir)

Compiler error is:  `error: assignment of read-only reference 's'`

*Now in my actual case the list is made of member variables on a class.*

Now, this doesn't work because the expression becomes an `initializer_list<int>` that actually copies a,b,c, and d - hence also not allowing modification.

My question is two-fold:

**Is there any motivation behind not allowing to write a range-based for loop in this way ?** *eg. perhaps there could be a special case for naked brace expressions.*

**What is a *syntactical neat* way of fixing this type of loop ?**

Something along this line would be preferred:

```
for (auto& s : something(a, b, c, d)) {
    s = 1;
}
```

**I do not consider pointer indirection a good solution (that is `{&a, &b, &c, &d}`) - any solution should give the element reference directly when the iterator is de-referenced**.

Comment: A simple workaround (that I wouldn't really use myself) is to create a list of pointers instead: `{ &a, &b, &c, &d }`.

Comment: `initializer_list` is mostly a view on `const` array.

Comment: What I would probably do is to explicitly initialize the variables, one by one. It's not going to be much more to write, it's clear and explicit, and it does what's intended. :)

Comment: if you don't want `{ &a, &b, &c, &d }`, you won't want neither: `for (auto& s : std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<int>>{a, b, c, d}) {
        s.get() = 1;
    }`

Comment: The questions "why isn't this able to work" is a very different question from "what can I do to make something like this work?"

Comment: You should always `#include <initializer_list>` to use that syntax; not doing so has undefined behaviour. Usually at least one other header has coincidentally indirectly included it for you, or the compiler will error, but those shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: `{&a, &b, &c, &d}` is fine. Without the ampersand, people would assume that you are passing in value and not address.

Answer (score 4):

Ranges are not as magic as people would like. In the end, there must be an object that the compiler can generate calls on to either a member function or free function `begin()` and `end()`.

Closest you'll probably be able to come is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a{},b{},c{},d{};

    for (auto s : {&a, &b, &c, &d} ) {
        *s = 1;
    }
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can drop `std::vector<int*>`.

Comment: @mhhollomon I explicitly stated im not interested in a pointer indirection solution.

Comment: It should be `auto s` or `auto* s`, not `auto& s`.

Comment: @darune - I'll be happy to have somebody give a different answer. It is not clear that such an answer exists with the current standard.

Comment: @L.F. - agreed.

Comment: This is the correct solution. All the other solutions are convoluted ways of doing exactly what this solution does.

Answer (score 4):

According to the standard *§11.6.4 List-initialization/p5 [dcl.init.list]* [**Emphasis Mine**]:

> An object of type 'std::initializer_list' is constructed from an
>   initializer list **as if the implementation generated and materialized
>   (7.4) a prvalue of type “array of N const E”**, where N is the number of
>   elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is
>   copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer
>   list, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer
>   to that array. [ Note: A constructor or conversion function selected
>   for the copy shall be accessible (Clause 14) in the context of the
>   initializer list. — end note ] If a narrowing conversion is required
>   to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.

Thus, your compiler is complaining legitimately (i.e., `auto &s` deducts to `int const& s` and you cannot assign to `s` in the ranged for loop).

You could alleviate this problem by introducing a container instead of an initializer list (e.g., `std::vector’) with ‘std::reference_wrapper’:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a{},b{},c{},d{};

    for (auto& s : std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>{a, b, c, d}) {
        s.get()= 1;
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/823831bbb3220dd0)

Comment: @Jarod42  Ouups sorry, amended that.

Comment: You solution does not fit my criteria for a nice solution - if i was happy with that I wouldn't have asked in the first place :)

Comment: also your quote does not attempt to answer my question

Comment: @darune - actually, the quote is the reason that your `for (auto& s : {a, b, c, d})` doesn't work.     As to why the standard has that clause ..... you'd have to ask members of the standardisation committee.   Like many such things, the reasoning could be anything between "We didn't consider your particular case was useful enough to bother about" through to "Too many other parts of the standard would have to change to support your case, and we postponed consideration of all that until we develop a future standard".

Comment: Can't you just use `std::array<std::reference_wrapper>>`?

Comment: Possibly: `s/vector/initializer_list/g`.

Answer (score 4):

Just another solution within a wrapper idea:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
class Ref_array {
    using Array = std::array<T*, size>;

    class Iterator {
    public:
        explicit Iterator(typename Array::iterator it) : it_(it) {}

        void operator++() { ++it_; }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { return it_ != other.it_; }
        decltype(auto) operator*() const { return **it_; }

    private:
        typename Array::iterator it_;
    };

public:
    explicit Ref_array(Array args) : args_(args) {}

    auto begin() { return Iterator(args_.begin()); }
    auto end() { return Iterator(args_.end()); }

private:
    Array args_;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
auto something(T& first, Ts&... rest) {
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...));
    return Ref_array<T, 1 + sizeof...(Ts)>({&first, &rest...});
}
```

Then:

```
int main() {
    int a{}, b{}, c{}, d{};

    for (auto& s : something(a, b, c, d)) {
        std::cout << s;
        s = 1;
    }

    std::cout  << std::endl;
    for (auto& s : something(a, b, c, d))
        std::cout << s;
}
```

outputs

```
0000
1111
```

Comment: This is a decent and good solution/workaround. Its an idea similiar to my own answer (I used a std::reference_wrapper and not using variadic template)

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy that syntax

```
for (auto& s : something{a, b, c, d}) {
    s = 1;
}
```

you might create wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyRefWrapper
{
public:
    MyRefWrapper(T& p)  : p(&p) {}

    T& operator =(const T& value) const { return *p = value; }

    operator T& () const { return *p; }
private:
    T* p;     
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb505a9fcb865e00)

Comment: How does that differ from `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: @TobySpeight: `std::reference_wrapper` would require `s.get() = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: use a reference wrapper

```
template <class It>
struct range_view_iterator : public It{//TODO: don't inherit It
    auto& operator*() {
        return (*this)->get();
    }
};

template<class It>
range_view_iterator(It) -> range_view_iterator<It>;


template<class T>
struct range_view {
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T> > refs_;
    range_view(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<T> > refs) : refs_{refs} {
    }

    auto begin() {
        return range_view_iterator{ refs_.begin() };
    }

    auto end() {
        return range_view_iterator{ refs_.end() };
    }
};
```

Then used as:

```
for (auto& e : range_view<int>{a, b, c, d}) {
    e = 1;
}
```

This doesn't try to answer the first question though.

Answer (score -1):

You could create wrapper class for storing reference and which will have assignment operator to update this value:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapper {
    T& ref;

    Wrapper(T& ref)
    : ref(ref){}

    template<class U>
    void operator=(U u) {
        ref = u;
    }
};

template<class...T>
auto sth(T&...t) {
    return std::array< Wrapper<std::common_type_t<T...> > ,sizeof...(t) >{Wrapper(t)...};
};

int main(){
    int a{},b{},c{},d{};

    for (auto s : sth(a,b,c,d)) {
        s = 1;
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // 1
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4LCf4q)