# Why is a type of range based for loop over brace-init list illegal c++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

This is a follow-up question to:

[Innocent range based for loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730476/innocent-range-based-for-loop-not-working)

In this question, the syntax that is used is:

```
    int a{},b{},c{},d{};

    for (auto& i : {a, b, c, d}) {
        i = 1;
    }
```

That is not legal c++. (In order to make it a work a new container type has to be invented that stores pointers or references internally)

Is this just a sort of a side-effect of two different concepts or why was it not allowed ?

At first this look like a miss in regard to driving the language forward, but knowing much work goes into these things Im guessing it was problematic or perhaps just not considered very much.

Im speculating answers might be something like:

It was problematic in some way, given how `initializer_list`/arrays/brace-init lists/etc. were designed (and 'fixing' that would either be too hard for compiler writers or would perform less optimal in the generel case).

It would require a special rule or it could potentially be allowed with some fundamental language change (eg. to `initializer_list`).

It would be ambiguous / unclear to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because it isn't supposed to work. That's the design of the feature. That feature being [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which as the name suggests is about initializing something.

When C++11 introduced `initializer_list`, it was done for precisely one purpose: to allow the system to generate an array of values from a braced-init-list and pass them to a properly-tagged constructor (possibly indirectly) so that the object could initialize itself with that sequence of values. The "proper tag" in this case being that the constructor took the newly-minted `std::initializer_list` type as its first/only parameter. That's the purpose of `initializer_list` as a type.

Initialization, broadly speaking, should not *modify* the values it is given. The fact that the array backing the list is a temporary also doubles-down on the idea that the input values should logically be non-modifiable. If you have:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

We want to give the compiler the freedom to make that array of 5 elements a static array in the compiled binary, rather than a stack array that bloats the stack size of this function. More to the point, we logically want to think of the braced-init-list like a literal.

And we don't allow literals to be modified.

Your attempt to make `{a, b, c, d}` into a range of modifiable references is essentially trying to take a construct that already exists for one purpose and turn it into a construct for a different purpose. You're not initializing anything; you're just using a seemingly convenient syntax that happens to make iterable lists of values. But that syntax is called a "braced-*init*-list", and it generates an *initializer* list; the terminology is not an accident.

If you take a tool intended for X and try to hijack it do Y, you're likely to encounter rough edges somewhere down the road. So the reason why it doesn't work is that this it's *not meant to*; these are not what braced-init-lists and `initializer_list`s are for.

You might next say "if that's the case, why does `for(auto i: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})` work at all, if braced-init-lists are only for initialization?"

Once upon a time, it *didn't*; in C++11, that would be il-formed. It was only in C++14 when `auto l = {1, 2, 3, 4};` became legal syntax; an `auto` variable was allowed to automatically deduce a braced-init-list as an `initializer_list`.

Range-based `for` uses `auto` deduction for the range type, so it inherited this ability. This naturally led people to believe that braced-init-lists are about building ranges of values, not initializing things.

In short, someone's convenience feature led you to believe that a construct meant to initialize an objects is just a quick way to create an array. It never was.

---

Having established that braced-init-lists aren't *supposed* to do the thing you want them to do, what would it take to make them do what you want?

Well, there are basically two ways to do it: small scale and large scale. The large-scale version would be to change how `auto i = {a, b, c, d};` works, so that it could (based on something) create a modifiable range of references to expressions. Range-based `for` would just use its existing `auto`-deduction machinery to pick up on it.

This is of course a non-starter. That definition already has a well-defined meaning: it creates a non-modifiable list of copies of those expressions, not references to their results. Changing it would be a breaking change.

A small-scale change would be to hack range-based `for` to do some fancy deduction based on whether the range expression is a braced-init-list or not. Now, because such ranges and their iterators are buried by the compiler-generated code for range-based `for`, you won't have as many backwards compatibility problems. So you could do make a rule where, if your range-statement defines a non-`const` reference variable, and the range-expression is a braced-init-list, then you do some different deduction mechanisms.

The biggest problem here is that it's a complete and total hack. If it's useful to do `for(auto &i : {a, b, c d})`, then it's probably useful to be able to get the same kind of range *outside* of a range-based `for` loop. As it currently stands, the rules about `auto`-deduction of braced-init-lists are consistent everywhere. Range-based `for` gains its capabilities simply because it uses `auto` deduction.

The last thing C++ needs is *more inconsistency*.

This is doubly important in light of C++20 [adding an init-statement to range-`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). These two things ought to be equivalent:

```
for(auto &i : {a, b, c, d})
for(auto &&rng = {a, b, c, d}; auto &i: rng)
```

But if you change the rules only based on the range-expression and range-statement, they wouldn't be. `rng` would be deduced according to existing `auto` rules, thus making the `auto &i` non-functional. And having a super-special-case rule that changes how the init-statement of a range-`for` behaves, different from the same statement in other locations, would be even more inconsistent.

Besides, it's not too difficult to write a generic `reference_range` function that takes non-`const` variadic reference parameters (of the same type) and returns some kind of random-access range over them. That will work everywhere equally and without compatibility problems.

So let's just avoid trying to make a syntactic construct intended for initializing objects into a generic "list of stuff" tool.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most important part about why this is invalid is reason given at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (since C++14, emphasis mine):

> **The underlying array is a temporary array of type `const T[N]`**, in which
>   each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions
>   are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original
>   initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as
>   any other temporary object, except that initializing an
>   initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the
>   array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same
>   exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The
>   **underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory**.

So giving reference to non-const in for loop is invalid. Also as noted in comment, array of references is not valid C++ construct

Relevant cpp standard read: http://eel.is/c++draft/support.initlist.access

Comment: And array of references is not legal.

Comment: This is not answering the question really: so you saying this is because its an array underlying - but as shown in the linked post it wouldn't need to be like that. Eg. i can make a type taking `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<T> >` as constructor argument.

Comment: @darune: And under what circumstances would you decide that a braced-init-list should generate an array of this class? Because the for loop is using auto-deduction to generate the array, so there is no larger context besides the contents of the list. If someone should *want* to create a list of pointers, or just a list of integers, how would you tell the difference?

Comment: @NicolBolas the type is given on the left hand side in the for loop as it is, eg. `for(auto& e : ...)`- it makes a little bit sad language-wise this isn't built-in *somehow* (..and im aware it's a lot to ask)

Comment: @darune: "*the type is given on the left hand side in the for loop*" No, it's not. That's not how range-based for loops work.

Comment: @NicolBolas right, im not arguing how it works. Im asking why. I think it's possible to make a list type that can support both value and reference semantics depending on the input.  In the other question I showed a method using reference_wrapper that is only intended for references and not generalized - but shouldn't that be possible (to generalize) ?

Comment: @darune: "*I think it's possible to make a list type that can support both value and reference semantics depending on the input.*" Sure, it's "possible", but what does that matter? Whatever that type is and whatever its behavior might be, that type is not `initializer_list`, as that's not the purpose of `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 4):

> It would require a special rule or it could potentially be allowed with some fundamental language change (eg. to `initializer_list`).

The change would indeed need to be fundamental. The problem is not with how `initializer_list` is implemented though.

According to [[dcl.ref]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#5):

> There shall be no references to references, **no arrays of references**, and no pointers to references.

This makes sense since a reference is not an object in the strict sense. A reference is not required to have storage.

Since arrays of references are not legal, these are a few workarounds:

Use an array of pointers

```
for (auto* i : {&a, &b, &c, &d}) {
    *i = 1;
}
```

Flavours using `std::reference_wrapper`. Note that I've used `int&` instead of `auto&` to not have to use `i.get() = 1`:

```
for (int& i : {std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c), std::ref(d)}) {
    i = 1;
}
```

```
for (int& i : std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<int>>{a,b,c,d}) {
    i = 1;
}
```

If you use it a lot, make a helper:

```
template<typename T>
using refwrap = std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<T>>;

for (int& i : refwrap<int>{a,b,c,d}) {
    i = 1;
}
```

Comment: `i.get() = 1;` with `std::reference_wrapper`, that is why alternative classes has been created in previous question.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, if `auto&` is used. I should perhaps make a note that I used `int&` to make that clearer. Edit: Note added.